# How to have an Apps Script Gadget display results directly in the UI

Tags: gwt, google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

On my [Google Site](http://www.onsitebac.com/viewmyblows) I've inserted an Apps Script Gadget (by pasting the URL of an Apps Script that I published as a service). This Apps Script allows the user to enter a value (their 'Blow Number') and view the corresponding data (based on API calls to my Google Fusion tables).

Right now, the script returns 3 hyperlinks:

- Click here for a table of Blow Number 1
- Click here for a chart of Blow Number 1
- Click here for a map of Blow Number 1

This is because my script function `getblowdetails` has 3 `app.createAnchor` variables. Instead of having the script return 3 hyperlinks (that the user has to click on and view the resulting URL in a new window), I would like for the script to automatically invoke the 3 URLs and display the table, chart, and map in panels on the same page.

So the user would enter their Blow Number and press enter. They would then view the table, chart, and map directly below the text box on the same web page.

Please see the **Code** that I've included below and advise...Thanks for the help- I'm an apps-script novice so a thorough and understand-able response is greatly appreciated!

### Code

*Note: I've removed the URLs from the createAnchor variables because I'm only allowed to include 2 links in the post, but you can see them by going to www.OnSiteBAC.com/ViewMyBlows and entering Blow Number = 1...then click on the hyperlinks.*

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  // Create input boxes, buttons, labels, and links
  var textBoxA = app.createTextBox().setId('textBoxA').setName('textBoxA').setFocus(true);
  var buttonA = app.createButton('Get Blow Details').setEnabled(false);
  var label = app.createLabel('Please enter your Blow Number here');
  var link = app.createAnchor('where can I find my Blow Number?', 'http://www.onsitebac.com');

  // Create a handler to call the getblowdetails function.
  // A validation is added to this handler so that it will only invoke 'getblowdetails' if textBoxA contains a number
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('getblowdetails').validateNumber(textBoxA).addCallbackElement(textBoxA);

  // Create a handler to enable the button if all input is legal
  var onValidInput = app.createClientHandler().validateNumber(textBoxA).forTargets(buttonA).setEnabled(true).forTargets(label, link).setVisible(false);

  // Create a handler to mark invalid input in textBoxA and disable the button
  var onInvalidInput1 = app.createClientHandler().validateNotNumber(textBoxA).forTargets(buttonA).setEnabled(false).forTargets(textBoxA).setStyleAttribute("color", "red").forTargets(label, link).setVisible(true);

  // Create a handler to mark the input in textBoxA as valid
  var onValidInput1 = app.createClientHandler().validateNumber(textBoxA).forTargets(textBoxA).setStyleAttribute("color", "black");

  // only fire ServerHandler for onKeyUp if it passes validation
  var textBoxHandler = app.createServerHandler('textBoxHandlerFunction');

  // Add all the handlers to be called when the user types in the text boxes
  textBoxHandler.addCallbackElement(textBoxA);
  textBoxA.addKeyUpHandler(onInvalidInput1);
  textBoxA.addKeyUpHandler(onValidInput1);
  textBoxA.addKeyUpHandler(onValidInput);
  textBoxA.addKeyUpHandler(textBoxHandler);
  buttonA.addClickHandler(handler);
  app.add(textBoxA);
  app.add(buttonA);
  app.add(label);
  app.add(link);
  return app;
}

function textBoxHandlerFunction(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  if (e.parameter.keyCode == 13)
  {
    app = getblowdetails(e);
  }
  return app;
}

function getblowdetails(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var panel2 = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var link2 = app.createAnchor ().setStyleAttribute("color", "green");
  var panel3 = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var link3 = app.createAnchor ();
  var panel4 = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var link4 = app.createAnchor ();
  panel3.add(link3);
  app.add(panel3);
  panel4.add(link4);
  app.add(panel4);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure whether this is possible. You might hit the CORS related issue. Did you already try https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideHttpRequests

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to actually download the result and show it. So, there's no easy solution.

But you can build that table and chart on Apps Script easily (assuming you can already fetch the info from tables using its API).

The last issue is the map. On Apps Script you can only create static maps, meaning, an image. You can add custom markers and polygons, set the zoom, etc. But in the end it's a photo. The user will not be able to drag it around or use the map as an embedded google map as one would expect.

Comment: Hi Henrique- thanks for the response- can you provide some sample code (based on what I included above) that shows how I can build the table and chart using apps script?

Here's a simpler example- it may be easier for you to provide sample code that uses this URL to fetch the data: https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT 'BLOWNUM', 'BACLEVEL' FROM 1KJeLOFHsMyJhjx11W5WXvJVejS-3C1tfz4nZFas WHERE 'BLOWNUM' = '1'&key=AIzaSyCJS9Zs6_C_y4cu_CIIsXDKts1kECyIuGo